# How to specify utc or local on a date string

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

Given a ui control that when you select 01/01/2017 it returns a Javascript date as `"Sun Jan 01 2017 05:00:00 GMT+0000"` (note, an actual Javascript Date object) so its not a string...

However, I definitely need the date part (01/01/2017) and "as UTC"

C# has a `DateTime.SpecifyKind(datetimevalue, DateTimeKind kind)` method

Basically whats the equivalent to this that doesnt *convert it*:

`moment(vm.theDate).specifyKind(utc)`

Looking for to get a moment instance that is 01/01/2017, isUtc=true, from that type of Javascript Date UI control.  (Its the Angular ui-datepicker control)

Comment: Read the documentation. It's right there in the menu: Parse - UTC: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/.

Answer (score 0):

You should look in the UI control's docs for a way to retrieve the selected value as a string instead of a date object.  A date object will be influenced by the local time zone, which will throw off your results - especially around DST transitions.  Many good datepicker controls will offer this as a separate property (ex, `theControl.value` or `theControl.text` instead of `theControl.date`).  Without knowing the specific control you are using, I can't offer anything more specific.

Once you have the string, use `moment.utc(yourInputString, yourInputFormat)`